# addition of combinations of two-dimensional array list

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, combinations

So the problem I'm working on solving involves an array list of array list of integers 
. What is known: The number of elements in each ArrayList of integers.  What is NOT known: How many ArrayList of Integers there actually are. I need suggestions for an algorithm that would sum the (ordered) elements of these arrays in every combination possible OF the arrays.  In order to clarify what I mean by this let me give an example:

```
AoA = [[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]];
```

Sum the elements of AoA[0] + AoA[1]; AoA[0]+AoA[2]; AoA[0]+AoA[3]; AoA[1]+AoA[2]; AoA[1]+AoA[3]; AoA[2]+AoA[3];

(4 choose 2)

So if anyone could code this simple version I'd be grateful as I'm struggling to do it.  If anyone could code the more complex example where there's an unknown number of arrays in the AoA (so N choose 2), you'd be my hero.

TL;DR/edit

I need an algorithm to take n-choose-2 arrays from an array of arrays; sum the arrays (e.g. [1,2,3] + [1,2,3] = [2,4,6]); put the add the new summed array into an array of arrays.

Comment: The problem is presumably not the addition.  The problem is generating the combinations, right?

Comment: If you are using ArrayLists throughout, then size is easily determined by an ArrayList.size() call.  As @OliCharlesworth says, it sounds like the problem is a combinatorial one.

Comment: Is the 2 in (N choose 2) fixed?

Comment: The question is very unclear.  If you have the data structure, then you know how many ArrayLists.  Do you just want an algorithm to get  the n-choose-2 pairs of numbers you could pick from 0..n-1, in order to use those pairs as indices?  Need to edit the question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth et al. : yes, that's correct.  I'm looking for the algorithm to pick the n-choose-2 arrays to then perform the addition with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've got, took me a while but this will do what I was looking for:
it takes each combination of the arrays (t1, t2, t3, t4) and adds their elements and returns whatever combinatorial you choose for n, (in this example i left it as 3).

If there's any more optimizations you can see please feel free to add it. I'm a perl guy so making this work at all in Java was a real task.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class testnCk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<int[]> sums = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        int [] t1 = {1,1,0,0};
        int [] t2 = {1,0,0,1};
        int [] t3 = {0,0,0,0};
        int [] t4 = {0,0,1,1};
        ArrayList<int[]> testing = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        testing.add(t1);
        testing.add(t2);
        testing.add(t3);
        testing.add(t4);

        int n = 3;
        int i = -1;
        int[] array = new int[4];
        ArrayList<int[]> whatever = nCk(testing, sums, array, i, n);

        for (int[] test1 : whatever)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < test1.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(test1[j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static ArrayList<int[]> nCk (ArrayList<int[]> arrayOfDiffPatterns, ArrayList<int[]> solutions, int[] tempsums, int i, int n)
    {
        n--;
        for (int j=i+1; j<arrayOfDiffPatterns.size(); j++){
            int[] array = tempsums.clone();
            for (int k=0; k<arrayOfDiffPatterns.get(0).length; k++){
                    array[k] += arrayOfDiffPatterns.get(j)[k];
            }
            if(n>0){
                nCk(arrayOfDiffPatterns, solutions, array, j, n);
            }
            else{
                solutions.add(array);
            }
        }
        return solutions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 is fixed then the easiest thing I can think about is just generating the new array with `N*(N-1)/2` rows, one for each sum and then using two variables to iterate through the original array with something like:s

```
int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
      sums[c][k] = AoA[i][k] + AoA[j][k];
    }
    c++;
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the M variable in the last for loop?

Comment: M = number of elements in the arrays of ints, which you mentioned as something known.

Comment: Ok,I haven't tested your code yet but it looks similar to what I was contemplating but instead of using 4 for loops you used 3 and a c with an incrementer.  So in the case N and M both = 4, this new AoA sums will have 6 arrays within it with this code?

Comment: Going through it in my head it looks like it will create (N*N(-1)) rows not N*(N-1)/2 rows; not a big problem if that's the case just trying to understand the algorithm.

Comment: Well, lets see for `N=5` it will go like this: (i=0,j=1,2,3,4) (i=1,j=2,3,4), (i=2,j=3,4),(i=3,j=4). 10 results = (5*4/2)